# Why is my longtable being treated like a figure?

Tags: captions, longtable, appendix

I am using longtable for a multi-page table in an Appendix of a paper. I was able to get the table onto multiple pages and am content generally with how that turned out...

Unfortunately, my table is being treated like a figure in the template that I am using. It includes both of my long tables as figures and includes their captions in the figure captions list.

I tried to look up table captions for longtable, but need to also consider these specific instructions for the template as well:

```
%% Important!

%\appendcaption{<appendix letter and number>}{<caption>} 

%must be used for figures and tables in appendixes, e.g.,
%
```

When they were just tables *(that didn't properly fit on the page)*, I did not have these issues.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). For more helpful answers you'd better provide [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). See if this can help you https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/214551/91556, or https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/411584/91556.

Comment: Needless to say, \appendcaption is not standard LaTeX.

Comment: It seems part of a custom template of a journal to make some fancy floats, so your options are (1) not use `\appendcaption` and expect the editor's  benevolence, or (2) split your long table in several normal tables, or (3) ask the editor, who probably will require you to adapt to the template constrains.